# After GroupBy, condense multiple records in a group into one

Tags: c#, linq

**Context**

I have a POCO like this:

```cs
public class Schedule
{
    string ScheduleType
    string DayOfWeek
    int Id
    string Description
    DateTime StartDateTime
    DateTime EndDateTime
    List<string> GroupedDaysOfWeek
}
```

And I have a LINQ query that retrieves `List<Schedule>`, which I then group by Id, StartDateTime, EndDateTime.

```cs
schedule.GroupBy(s => new { s.Id, s.StartDateTime, s.EndDateTime })
```

This gives me several groups, with each records in a group having different DayOfWeek (MONDAY, TUESDAY, etc), with the same Id, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, like this per group:

```cs
Schedule1 - 1/1/2020 9:00:00AM, 12/31/2021 11:59:59AM, 37, MONDAY
Schedule2 - 1/1/2020 9:00:00AM, 12/31/2021 11:59:59AM, 37, TUESDAY
Schedule3 - 1/1/2020 9:00:00AM, 12/31/2021 11:59:59AM, 37, WEDNESDAY
Schedule4 - 1/1/2020 9:00:00AM, 12/31/2021 11:59:59AM, 37, THURSDAY
Schedule5 - 1/1/2020 9:00:00AM, 12/31/2021 11:59:59AM, 37, FRIDAY
```

**What I would like to do:**
Take these records *per group* and squish them into one record, using List GroupedDaysOfWeek, like this:

```cs
Schedule1 - 1/1/2020 9:00:00AM, 12/31/2021 11:59:59AM, 37, List(MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY)
```

**What I have tried:**
I am new to LINQ and have tried using `.Select()` or `.Aggregate()` after the `.GroupBy()`without success.

Comment: probably you could help with sample data and desired outcome

Comment: Try following var results = schedule.GroupBy(s => new { s.Id, s.StartDateTime, s.EndDateTime }).Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
var groups = schedule.GroupBy(s => new { s.Id, s.StartDateTime, s.EndDateTime })
                     .Select(g => new { key = g.Key, days = g.Select(schedule=> schedule.DayOfWeek)});
```

this will return an `IEnumerable` of an anonymous object containing your key and an `IEnumerable` of the days of the week.

Comment: This is great! Is there a way to assign this ```IEnumerable``` to List<string> GroupedDaysOfWeek field in the Schedule class?

Comment: not really, because this doesnt return a Schedule object. you can create a new class with Id, StartDateTime EndDateTime and that list, and do something like this: `.Select(g => new MyClass(g.Key.Id, g.Key.StartDateTime, g.Key.EndDateTime ,g.Select(schedule=> schedule.DayOfWeek).ToList())`

Comment: I see. I think I will do exactly what you are suggesting! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get results in the Schedule Class

```
          var results = schedule.GroupBy(s => new { s.Id, s.StartDateTime, s.EndDateTime })
              .Select(x => new Schedule()
              {
                  ScheduleType = x.First().ScheduleType,
                  Id = x.Key.Id,
                  Description = x.First().Description,
                  StartDateTime = x.Key.StartDateTime,
                  EndDateTime = x.Key.EndDateTime,
                  GroupedDaysOfWeek = x.Select(y => y.DayOfWeek).ToList()
              }).ToList();
```